# Setting up an SVN repository on a subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I've found a few guides for setting up a subversion repository and making it available via a subdomain (using a virtual host  in Apache), but for some reason can't get things working. Here's what I've got so far:

1. Created a subdomain "svn.mydomain.com"
2. Configured Apache with a new VirtualHost:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin info@mydomain.com
       ServerName svn.mydomain.com
       <location>
           DAV svn
           SVNPath /Volumes/Storage/Resources/Subversion/svn_repo
       </location>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

For now I don't have any authentication set up (to keep things simple until I get this working).

Am I missing something obvious? If not, any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  That might help narrow down what is going on.  Also make sure somewhere in your configuration you are loading the dav module with `LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so`

Comment: Ah, looks like I don't have mod_dav_svn installed/configured. I'll get that going and see if that gets things working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your htpasswd file and tell SVN about it. Here are my notes on setting up SVN on Centos 5.5:

```
Install SVN
# yum install mod_dav_svn subversion

Create the SVN Config File
# vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf

Add the first repo to the file above
<Location /domain.com>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /var/www/svn/domain.com
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion Repo"
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
   Require valid-user
</Location>

Create the password file
# htpasswd -cm /etc/svn-auth-conf yourusername

Create another user
# htpasswd -m /etc/svn-auth-conf anotherusername

Create repository
# svnadmin create /var/www/svn/domain.com

Set Permissions
# chown apache -R /var/www/svn
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a old question, but i ran with this problem and i was able to setup the subdomain to host all my repositories following this tutorial

http://dhruba.name/2011/05/23/installing-subversion-using-subdomain-on-apache-and-debian/

just mention on "SVNParentPath" you should enter the absolute path , ex: "/var/www/svn/" ,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Directory access rights were the reason. If you do not provide `DocumentRoot`, then Apache chooses its default `DocumentRoot`. And if an access to the default `DocumentRoot` is denied -- then SVN is also denied.

Just set `DocumentRoot` in your VirtualHost to an existing, empty directory and in a `<Directory>` section grant the `allow` right to that directory.